# What does the "set R- {-1}" mean???

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I am trying to answer the question: On the set R-{-1} define the operations a⊕b=a+b+aba⊕b=a+b+ab and axb=0axb=0. Determine if (R - {-1}, ⊕, x) is a ring. Is it a commutative ring with unity?

However I have no idea what this set even is/looks like. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you posted the same question 43 min ago. why do you post again ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if R is a commutative ring with unity?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728263/determine-if-r-is-a-commutative-ring-with-unity)

Answer (score 3):

This is R, the set of all real numbers with the set {-1} removed.  That is, the set of all real numbers **except** -1.

Answer (score 2):

The notation $R-\{-1\}$ means the same thing as $R\setminus \{-1\}$. They both denote the set $\{x\in R\mid x\neq -1\}$.

(In general, $A - B$ and $A\setminus B$ are notations for the set $\{x\mid x\in A\text{ and }x\notin B\}$.)